# Localizing applications: difference between gnugettext and dxgettext

Tags: delphi, localization

Are gnugettext and dxgettext 2 totally different tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dxgettext is for Delphi specifically. It is based on GNU tools, but provides some specific helper tools targeted for Borland developers only. So, if you are on Delphi - go for it. On other platforms dxgettext is useless.

Comment: "Borland developers" - how about Embarcadero developers? :)

Comment: I think an Embarcadero developer should recieve a salary from Embarcadero ;)

Comment: I am sorry, Delphi for me is always "Borland" :)